# ElasticSearch/Kibana - Get count of unique session Ids

Tags: kibana

I am new to Kibana. Appreciate if somebody help me to solve this problem.
I want to show count of unique session Ids in a given period of time on the Dashboard.
I use Data Table but it shows aggregation at the session_id level.

```
session_ids      count
-----------      ------
123456             5
78012              12
56453423           2
```

I want to show on the dashboard the count of unique session_ids

Count = 3

Thanks,
Manoj

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To build a dashboard like this in Kibana you should go to Visualize -> Select your Index -> Select a Vertical Bar chart and then in the visualize panel:

In the Y axis you want the unique count of session_ids (select the field where you stored the session_ids) and in the X axis we want a date histogram with your timefield.

Your Visualization will look something like below :

[image]

You may also do the same with data table. your visualization will look like :

[image]

Comment: pls do you know how to remove "count" from "tooltip" on coordinate map in Kibana?